# Django template translation with variable order

Tags: django

I want to translate a string in a Django template:

```
{% trans "Thank you. You may <a href=\"/logout\">log out</a> now." %}
```

So in English, the result would be:

```
Thank you, You may <log out> now.
```

But - as an example in German, I need:

```
Vielen Dank. Sie können sich nun <ausloggen>.
```

Where the text in <> is the hyperlink. Now the problem is that the order of words has changed, and I do not find a way how to do this. I did see in the documentation that this can be done in Python code, with "placeholders". But I need it in templates. Is there a way to do it? Also, to ease translation, I don't like HTML in my translation file. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640084/django-templates-best-practice-for-translating-text-block-with-html-in-it

Comment: I don't undestand what is your problem. Just write the words in the translation in any order you want. It absolutely doesn't matter that there's a hyperlink in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fsw recommended, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640084/django-templates-best-practice-for-translating-text-block-with-html-in-it).

You should not hardcode the "/logout", you have to use `{% url "urlname" %}` tag.
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

maybe that? (i didnt test it)

```
{% url "logout" as logoutvar %}

{% blocktrans with logoutvar as logoutvar %}

"Thank you. You may <a href="{{ logoutvar }}">log out</a> now."

{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Daniel,  Did you solve the words order with bloktrans ?? I have similar issues with spanish - english