# Django blocktrans - inside HTML tag

Tags: django, localization

Is it possible to put some HTML tag inside this Django block: {% blocktrans %}{% endblocktrans %}?

For example:

```
{% blocktrans %}Django<br>framework needed{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly, sometimes you even *have* to use `blocktrans` template tag actually.

Check:

- [Translating text blocks with Django .. what to do with the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397218/translating-text-blocks-with-django-what-to-do-with-the-html)
- [Django templates: Best practice for translating text block with HTML in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640084/django-templates-best-practice-for-translating-text-block-with-html-in-it)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/j_r6y1VeAag

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html):

> HTML markup, however, is common enough that it's probably ok to use in translatable strings. But please bear in mind that the GNU
>   gettext tools don't verify that the translations are well-formed HTML.